# autofocus in react based on condition if else

Tags: reactjs, autofocus, refs

How to autofocus for input name based on whether this.props.email exists or not?

```
if(this.props.email){
    // would like to set autofocus for  <input value={email} name="userName">    
}else{
   // would like to set autofocus for  <input name="password" />
}

 <input value={email} name="userName">             
 <input name="password" />
```

I was thinking of using refs but is wondering if there is better way to access the name of the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may want to try this

```
<input value={email} autoFocus={this.props.email} name="userName">
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use !!this.props.email ?

Comment: what does !!this.props.email means? is it same as {this.props.email}?

Comment: both {this.props.email} and {!!this.props.email} works but I was wondering what is the difference between {this.props.email} and {{!!this.props.email}}?

 {{!!this,props.email}} works for email is undefined case but not {this.props.email}}?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but that's right, !!this.props.email cover undefined case, it may don't matter here, but overall it's better to use for safety.

Answer (score 2):

### Checkout this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lr2r5n60xq)

This doesn't use **if-else**, but uses **this.props.email**, as in your question:

> How to autofocus for input name based on whether this.props.email exists or not?

---

Inside **Input.js** (component)

```
<input
  value={this.props.email}
  name="userName"
  autoFocus={this.props.email}
/>
<input name="password" autoFocus={!this.props.email} />
```

Inside **index.js** (parent)

```
<Input email={""} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `autofocus`:

```
<input value={email} name="userName" autofocus={!!this.props.email} >             
<input name="password" autofocus={!this.props.email} />
```

Or, with refs:

```
if(this.props.email){
    // would like to set autofocus for  <input value={email} name="userName">  
    this.emailInput.focus()  
}else{
    // would like to set autofocus for  <input name="password" />
    this.passwordInput.focus()
}

 <input value={email} name="userName" ref={input => {this.emailInput = input}}>             
 <input name="password" ref={input => {this.passwordInput = input}} />
```